# Pass in a variable amount of arguments to a program with assert?

Tags: lua

I'm using `assert(loadfile("file.lua"))(args)` with `args` as a table but it causes an error saying it's expecting a `string`. What I'm looking to do is have the user pass in arguments that get sent to a different program but the amount of arguments aren't known by the program. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What does `file.lua` do with its arguments? Do you just need to `unpack(args)` in the call there? What's the **exact** error you are getting?

Comment: here's exactly what I'm doing. I'm building an OS for the minecraft mod computercraft and I'm looking to have my custom shell execute another program. I have it gather user input and then it needs to execute the program with the syntax `<program> [args]`. The program itself does different things with the args depending and I already have a solution for programs that don't need args I just need to get the data in the table in the shell into the `args = {...}` table in my program.

Comment: The error you are getting is from something trying to use the `args` argument and expecting a string. Nothing about the line in your post does that. Something *else* is hitting this problem. That's why I asked about what `file.lua` is doing with the arguments and what **exact** error you were getting. There isn't enough information in the post to help you beyond my possible suggestion of using `unpack(args)` in that call.

Comment: This is what I'm doing inside of my program that I'm testing with. `args = {...} `and then I'm reading the data from that like I would a normal array. Ohhh wait I'm dumb...would I just do `args = ...` yea that fixed it